# Capping values after a trigger level in a different variable _after GroupBy

Tags: pandas, triggers, group-by

There was an elegant answer to a question almost like this provided by EdChum.  The difference between that question and this is that now the capping needs to be applied to data that had had "GroupBy" performed.

Original Data:

```
Symbol  DTE     Spot    Strike  Vol
AAPL    30.00   100.00  80.00   14.58
AAPL    30.00   100.00  85.00   16.20
AAPL    30.00   100.00  90.00   18.00
AAPL    30.00   100.00  95.00   20.00
AAPL    30.00   100.00  100.00  22.00
AAPL    30.00   100.00  105.00  25.30
AAPL    30.00   100.00  110.00  29.10
AAPL    30.00   100.00  115.00  33.46
AAPL    30.00   100.00  120.00  38.48
AAPL    50.00   102.00  80.00   13.08
AAPL    50.00   102.00  85.00   14.70
AAPL    50.00   102.00  90.00   16.50
AAPL    50.00   102.00  95.00   18.50
AAPL    50.00   102.00  100.00  20.50
AAPL    50.00   102.00  105.00  23.80
AAPL    50.00   102.00  110.00  27.60
AAPL    50.00   102.00  115.00  31.96
AAPL    50.00   102.00  120.00  36.98
 IBM    30.00   170.00  150.00  7.29
 IBM    30.00   170.00  155.00  8.10
 IBM    30.00   170.00  160.00  9.00
 IBM    30.00   170.00  165.00  10.00
 IBM    30.00   170.00  170.00  11.00
 IBM    30.00   170.00  175.00  12.65
 IBM    30.00   170.00  180.00  14.55
 IBM    30.00   170.00  185.00  16.73
 IBM    30.00   170.00  190.00  19.24
 IBM    60.00   171.00  150.00  5.79
 IBM    60.00   171.00  155.00  6.60
 IBM    60.00   171.00  160.00  7.50
 IBM    60.00   171.00  165.00  8.50
 IBM    60.00   171.00  170.00  9.50
 IBM    60.00   171.00  175.00  11.15
 IBM    60.00   171.00  180.00  13.05
 IBM    60.00   171.00  185.00  15.23
 IBM    60.00   171.00  190.00  17.74
```

I then create a few new variables:

```
df['ATM_dist'] =abs(df['Spot']-df['Strike'])

imin = df.groupby(['DTE','Symbol'])['ATM_dist'].transform('idxmin')

df['NormStrike']=np.log(df['Strike']/df['Spot'])/(((df['DTE']/365)**.5)*df['ATMvol']/100)

df['ATMvol'] = df.loc[imin,'Vol'].values
```

The results are below:

```
   Symbol  DTE  Spot  Strike    Vol  ATM_dist  ATMvol  NormStrike
0    AAPL   30   100      80  14.58        20    22.0   -3.537916
1    AAPL   30   100      85  16.20        15    22.0   -2.576719
2    AAPL   30   100      90  18.00        10    22.0   -1.670479
3    AAPL   30   100      95  20.00         5    22.0   -0.813249
4    AAPL   30   100     100  22.00         0    22.0    0.000000
5    AAPL   30   100     105  25.30         5    22.0    0.773562
6    AAPL   30   100     110  29.10        10    22.0    1.511132
7    AAPL   30   100     115  33.46        15    22.0    2.215910
8    AAPL   30   100     120  38.48        20    22.0    2.890688
9    AAPL   50   102      80  13.08        22    20.5   -3.201973
10   AAPL   50   102      85  14.70        17    20.5   -2.402955
11   AAPL   50   102      90  16.50        12    20.5   -1.649620
12   AAPL   50   102      95  18.50         7    20.5   -0.937027
13   AAPL   50   102     100  20.50         2    20.5   -0.260994
14   AAPL   50   102     105  23.80         3    20.5    0.382049
15   AAPL   50   102     110  27.60         8    20.5    0.995172
16   AAPL   50   102     115  31.96        13    20.5    1.581035
17   AAPL   50   102     120  36.98        18    20.5    2.141961
18    IBM   30   170     150   7.29        20    11.0   -3.968895
19    IBM   30   170     155   8.10        15    11.0   -2.929137
20    IBM   30   170     160   9.00        10    11.0   -1.922393
21    IBM   30   170     165  10.00         5    11.0   -0.946631
22    IBM   30   170     170  11.00         0    11.0    0.000000
23    IBM   30   170     175  12.65         5    11.0    0.919188
24    IBM   30   170     180  14.55        10    11.0    1.812480
25    IBM   30   170     185  16.73        15    11.0    2.681295
26    IBM   30   170     190  19.24        20    11.0    3.526940
27    IBM   60   171     150   5.79        21     9.5   -3.401827
28    IBM   60   171     155   6.60        16     9.5   -2.550520
29    IBM   60   171     160   7.50        11     9.5   -1.726243
30    IBM   60   171     165   8.50         6     9.5   -0.927332
31    IBM   60   171     170   9.50         1     9.5   -0.152273
32    IBM   60   171     175  11.15         4     9.5    0.600317
33    IBM   60   171     180  13.05         9     9.5    1.331704
34    IBM   60   171     185  15.23        14     9.5    2.043051
35    IBM   60   171     190  17.74        19     9.5    2.735427
```

I wish to have the values of 'Vol' cap to the level where another column 'NormStrike' hits a trigger (in this case abs(NormStrike) >= 2 ). This new column, 'Desired_Level', created while leaving the 'Vol' column unchanged. The first cap should cause the Vol value at index location 0 to be 16.2 because the cap was triggered at index location 1 when NormStrike hit -2.576719.

Added clarification:
I am looking for a generic solution, that works away from the lowest abs(NormStrike) level in both directions to hit both the -2 and the +2 trigger. If it is not hit (which it might not be) then desired level is just original_level

An additional note, it will always be true that the abs(NormStrike) continues to grow in size from the min(abs(NormStrike)) level as it is a function of abs(distance from spot to strike)

the code that EdChum provided (prior to me bringing GroupBy into the mix) is below:

```
clip = 4
lower = df.loc[df['NS'] <= -clip, 'Vol'].idxmax() 
upper = df.loc[df['NS'] >= clip, 'Vol'].idxmin()


df['Original_level'] = df['Original_level'].clip(df.loc[lower,'Original_level'], df.loc[upper, 'Original_level'])
```

There are 2 issues, first, it did not work after groupby and second, if a particular group of data does not have a NS value that exceeds the "clip" value then it generates an error.  The ideal outcome would be, in this case, nothing is done to the Vol level for the particular Symbol/DTE group in question.

Ed suggested implementing a reset_index() but I am not sure how to use that to solve the issue.

I hope this was not to convoluted of a question

thank you for any assistance

Comment: Could explain a bit more about your logic? "The first cap should cause the Vol value at index location 0 to be 16.2 because the cap was triggered at index location 1 when NormStrike hit -2.576719". Why it is 16.20 instead of 14.58 for the first row? I thought the value ' -3.537916' would already trigger the cap. I looks like that you are trying to backfill current record with an observation in a future date?

Comment: thank you for the advice, I have added an "added clarification" statement to the original question

Comment: Just modify the code, do one round forward fill and then backward fill on desired_level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this to see whether it works out. I assume if the clip has been triggered, then NaN will be put. You can replace it by your customized choice.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# use np.where(criterion, x, y) to do a vectorized statement like if criterion is True, then set it to x, else set it to y

def func(group):
    group['Triggered'] = np.where((group['NormStrike'] >= 2) | (group['NormStrike'] <= -4), 'Yes', 'No')
    group['Desired_Level'] = np.where((group['NormStrike'] >= 2) | (group['NormStrike'] <= -4), np.nan, group['Vol'])
    group = group.fillna(method='ffill').fillna(method='bfill')
    return group

df = df.groupby(['Symbol', 'DTE']).apply(func)

Out[410]: 
   Symbol  DTE  Spot  Strike    Vol  ATM_dist  ATMvol  NormStrike Triggered  Desired_Level
0    AAPL   30   100      80  14.58        20      22     -3.5379        No          14.58
1    AAPL   30   100      85  16.20        15      22     -2.5767        No          16.20
2    AAPL   30   100      90  18.00        10      22     -1.6705        No          18.00
3    AAPL   30   100      95  20.00         5      22     -0.8132        No          20.00
4    AAPL   30   100     100  22.00         0      22      0.0000        No          22.00
5    AAPL   30   100     105  25.30         5      22      0.7736        No          25.30
6    AAPL   30   100     110  29.10        10      22      1.5111        No          29.10
7    AAPL   30   100     115  33.46        15      22      2.2159       Yes          29.10
8    AAPL   30   100     120  38.48        20      22      2.8907       Yes          29.10
9    AAPL   50   102      80  14.58        22      22     -3.5379        No          14.58
10   AAPL   50   102      85  16.20        17      22     -2.5767        No          16.20
11   AAPL   50   102      90  18.00        12      22     -1.6705        No          18.00
12   AAPL   50   102      95  20.00         7      22     -0.8132        No          20.00
13   AAPL   50   102     100  22.00         2      22      0.0000        No          22.00
14   AAPL   50   102     105  25.30         3      22      0.7736        No          25.30
15   AAPL   50   102     110  29.10         8      22      1.5111        No          29.10
16   AAPL   50   102     115  33.46        13      22      2.2159       Yes          29.10
17   AAPL   50   102     120  38.48        18      22      2.8907       Yes          29.10
18   AAPL   30   170     150  14.58        20      22     -3.5379        No          14.58
19   AAPL   30   170     155  16.20        15      22     -2.5767        No          16.20
20   AAPL   30   170     160  18.00        10      22     -1.6705        No          18.00
21   AAPL   30   170     165  20.00         5      22     -0.8132        No          20.00
22   AAPL   30   170     170  22.00         0      22      0.0000        No          22.00
23   AAPL   30   170     175  25.30         5      22      0.7736        No          25.30
24   AAPL   30   170     180  29.10        10      22      1.5111        No          29.10
25   AAPL   30   170     185  33.46        15      22      2.2159       Yes          29.10
26   AAPL   30   170     190  38.48        20      22      2.8907       Yes          29.10
27   AAPL   60   171     150  14.58        21      22     -3.5379        No          14.58
28   AAPL   60   171     155  16.20        16      22     -2.5767        No          16.20
29   AAPL   60   171     160  18.00        11      22     -1.6705        No          18.00
30   AAPL   60   171     165  20.00         6      22     -0.8132        No          20.00
31   AAPL   60   171     170  22.00         1      22      0.0000        No          22.00
32   AAPL   60   171     175  25.30         4      22      0.7736        No          25.30
33   AAPL   60   171     180  29.10         9      22      1.5111        No          29.10
34   AAPL   60   171     185  33.46        14      22      2.2159       Yes          29.10
35   AAPL   60   171     190  38.48        19      22      2.8907       Yes          29.10
```

Comment: thank you much . . .the remaining issue is that I do not know how to replace NaN with the closest Vol level.  In essence, the first 2 NaN values in the above output should read 18.0 and 18.0.  The next 2 NaN values (index level 7&8) should read 29.1 and 29.1

Comment: It looks like you want to build a cross-Strike curve about desired vol level. The most common way to fill na is to use a cubic interpolation, so the curve is smoothed. Similar to the situation where you have to interpolate yield curve.

Comment: Not sure how to do a forward fill or backward fill in this situation.  As far as the curve, I actually have  a 4th order curve that is reliable, the issue is that my simulated stress test introduces data outside the range of the original data that was used to generated the 4th order and this is giving undesired results at the extreme ends

Comment: Indeed. From data, most NaNs requires extrapolation rather than interpolation.

Comment: new development that I do not think warrants a new question.  Using Jianxun's routine i am forces to have the trigger be abs(2) on both sides.  How would I have the trigger be -4 on the downside and +2 on the upside?

Comment: @John I've just rewrite the `apply_func` part to address the changes.

Comment: Thank you again, I was close,  I used & instead of | dumb mistake on my part.