# capping values based on sporadic trigger

Tags: python, pandas, triggers

I want to mention up front that this question is very close to question # 30990147

[Capping values after a trigger level in a different variable _after GroupBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30990147/capping-values-after-a-trigger-level-in-a-different-variable-after-groupby)

The difference being that in this situation, the variable that triggers the capping does not continue to trigger as we move further away from the center of the data.  In question 30990147 once the trigger was hit all subsequent values would also trigger the same cap.

Here is the situation, I need to examine for a trigger being hit in both directions from min(dist). In the below example I use a trigger of the first negative number hit on either side of min(dist).  min(dist) is at index=7 for the first "city/date" group.

I manually added the column is_capped and new_b to illustrate where the trigger levels take place

```
In [6]:

df
Out[6]:
       City       date  dist     a   b is_capped  new_b
0   Chicago  5/25/2015  6.55  0.10  36      True     37
1   Chicago  5/25/2015  3.93  0.16  21      True     37
2   Chicago  5/25/2015  3.27  0.06  32      True     37
3   Chicago  5/25/2015  2.62 -0.28  35      True     37
4   Chicago  5/25/2015  1.96  0.09  37     False     37
5   Chicago  5/25/2015  1.31  0.04  39     False     39
6   Chicago  5/25/2015  0.65  0.02  34     False     34
7   Chicago  5/25/2015  0.03  0.09  23     False     23
8   Chicago  5/25/2015  0.58  0.03  36     False     36
9   Chicago  5/25/2015  1.16  0.06  35     False     35
10  Chicago  5/25/2015  2.31  0.05  36     False     36
11  Chicago  5/25/2015  2.89 -0.41  20      True     36
12  Chicago  5/25/2015  3.47 -0.38  35      True     36
13  Chicago  6/16/2015  6.55  0.30  36      True     37
14  Chicago  6/16/2015  3.93  0.16  21      True     37
15  Chicago  6/16/2015  3.27  0.06  32      True     37
16  Chicago  6/16/2015  2.62 -0.28  35      True     37
17  Chicago  6/16/2015  1.96  0.09  37     False     37
18  Chicago  6/16/2015  1.31  0.04  39     False     39
19  Chicago  6/16/2015  0.65  0.02  34     False     34
20  Chicago  6/16/2015  0.03  0.09  23     False     23
21  Chicago  6/16/2015  0.58  0.03  36     False     36
22  Chicago  6/16/2015  1.16  0.06  35     False     35
23  Chicago  6/16/2015  2.31  0.05  36     False     36
24  Chicago  6/16/2015  2.89 -0.41  20      True     36
25  Chicago  6/16/2015  3.47 -0.38  35      True     36
26      NYC  2/22/2015  6.55  0.10  36      True     37
27      NYC  2/22/2015  3.93  0.16  21      True     37
28      NYC  2/22/2015  3.27  0.06  32      True     37
29      NYC  2/22/2015  2.62 -0.28  35      True     37
30      NYC  2/22/2015  1.96  0.09  37     False     37
31      NYC  2/22/2015  1.31  0.04  39     False     39
32      NYC  2/22/2015  0.65  0.02  34     False     34
33      NYC  2/22/2015  0.03  0.09  23     False     23
34      NYC  2/22/2015  0.58  0.03  36     False     36
35      NYC  2/22/2015  1.16  0.06  35     False     35
36      NYC  2/22/2015  2.31  0.05  36     False     36
37      NYC  2/22/2015  2.89 -0.41  20      True     36
38      NYC  2/22/2015  3.47 -0.38  35      True     36
39      NYC   5/5/2015  6.55  0.30  36      True     37
40      NYC   5/5/2015  3.93  0.16  21      True     37
41      NYC   5/5/2015  3.27  0.06  32      True     37
42      NYC   5/5/2015  2.62 -0.28  35      True     37
43      NYC   5/5/2015  1.96  0.09  37     False     37
44      NYC   5/5/2015  1.31  0.04  39     False     39
45      NYC   5/5/2015  0.65  0.02  34     False     34
46      NYC   5/5/2015  0.03  0.09  23     False     23
47      NYC   5/5/2015  0.58  0.03  36     False     36
48      NYC   5/5/2015  1.16  0.06  35     False     35
49      NYC   5/5/2015  2.31  0.05  36     False     36
50      NYC   5/5/2015  2.89 -0.41  20      True     36
51      NYC   5/5/2015  3.47 -0.38  35      True     36
```

I then group the data as follows:

```
gb = df.groupby(['City','date'])
```

and all seems fine:

```
In [6]:
gb.City.count()

Out[6]:
City     date     
Chicago  5/25/2015    13
         6/16/2015    13
NYC      2/22/2015    13
         5/5/2015     13
Name: City, dtype: int64
```

What I need is to look on both sides of min(dist) for the first occurrence of a<0.  In the first group (Chicago on 5/25/2015) the downside trigger occurs at index = 3 and therefore all values with a larger(abs(dist)) on the downside will have the same b level as the value just before the trigger (index =4).  The same thing happens on the upside starting from min(dist) and going up.  The upside trigger is at index level = 11 and further upside new_b values will all be set to the value of b at index = 10

Also, it is not necessary that there is ever a trigger at all.

Thank you for any assistance

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io  # I use py3.4

# your data
raw_data = ',City,date,dist,a,b\n0,Chicago,5/25/2015,6.55,0.1,36\n1,Chicago,5/25/2015,3.93,0.16,21\n2,Chicago,5/25/2015,3.27,0.06,32\n3,Chicago,5/25/2015,2.62,-0.28,35\n4,Chicago,5/25/2015,1.96,0.09,37\n5,Chicago,5/25/2015,1.31,0.04,39\n6,Chicago,5/25/2015,0.65,0.02,34\n7,Chicago,5/25/2015,0.03,0.09,23\n8,Chicago,5/25/2015,0.58,0.03,36\n9,Chicago,5/25/2015,1.16,0.06,35\n10,Chicago,5/25/2015,2.31,0.05,36\n11,Chicago,5/25/2015,2.89,-0.41,20\n12,Chicago,5/25/2015,3.47,-0.38,35\n13,Chicago,6/16/2015,6.55,0.3,36\n14,Chicago,6/16/2015,3.93,0.16,21\n15,Chicago,6/16/2015,3.27,0.06,32\n16,Chicago,6/16/2015,2.62,-0.28,35\n17,Chicago,6/16/2015,1.96,0.09,37\n18,Chicago,6/16/2015,1.31,0.04,39\n19,Chicago,6/16/2015,0.65,0.02,34\n20,Chicago,6/16/2015,0.03,0.09,23\n21,Chicago,6/16/2015,0.58,0.03,36\n22,Chicago,6/16/2015,1.16,0.06,35\n23,Chicago,6/16/2015,2.31,0.05,36\n24,Chicago,6/16/2015,2.89,-0.41,20\n25,Chicago,6/16/2015,3.47,-0.38,35\n26,NYC,2/22/2015,6.55,0.1,36\n27,NYC,2/22/2015,3.93,0.16,21\n28,NYC,2/22/2015,3.27,0.06,32\n29,NYC,2/22/2015,2.62,-0.28,35\n30,NYC,2/22/2015,1.96,0.09,37\n31,NYC,2/22/2015,1.31,0.04,39\n32,NYC,2/22/2015,0.65,0.02,34\n33,NYC,2/22/2015,0.03,0.09,23\n34,NYC,2/22/2015,0.58,0.03,36\n35,NYC,2/22/2015,1.16,0.06,35\n36,NYC,2/22/2015,2.31,0.05,36\n37,NYC,2/22/2015,2.89,-0.41,20\n38,NYC,2/22/2015,3.47,-0.38,35\n39,NYC,5/5/2015,6.55,0.3,36\n40,NYC,5/5/2015,3.93,0.16,21\n41,NYC,5/5/2015,3.27,0.06,32\n42,NYC,5/5/2015,2.62,-0.28,35\n43,NYC,5/5/2015,1.96,0.09,37\n44,NYC,5/5/2015,1.31,0.04,39\n45,NYC,5/5/2015,0.65,0.02,34\n46,NYC,5/5/2015,0.03,0.09,23\n47,NYC,5/5/2015,0.58,0.03,36\n48,NYC,5/5/2015,1.16,0.06,35\n49,NYC,5/5/2015,2.31,0.05,36\n50,NYC,5/5/2015,2.89,-0.41,20\n51,NYC,5/5/2015,3.47,-0.38,35\n'

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw_data), index_col=[0])

   Out[105]: 
          City       date  dist     a   b
   0   Chicago  5/25/2015  6.55  0.10  36
   1   Chicago  5/25/2015  3.93  0.16  21
   2   Chicago  5/25/2015  3.27  0.06  32
   3   Chicago  5/25/2015  2.62 -0.28  35
   4   Chicago  5/25/2015  1.96  0.09  37
   5   Chicago  5/25/2015  1.31  0.04  39
   6   Chicago  5/25/2015  0.65  0.02  34
   7   Chicago  5/25/2015  0.03  0.09  23
   8   Chicago  5/25/2015  0.58  0.03  36
   9   Chicago  5/25/2015  1.16  0.06  35
   10  Chicago  5/25/2015  2.31  0.05  36
   11  Chicago  5/25/2015  2.89 -0.41  20
   12  Chicago  5/25/2015  3.47 -0.38  35
   13  Chicago  6/16/2015  6.55  0.30  36
   14  Chicago  6/16/2015  3.93  0.16  21
   15  Chicago  6/16/2015  3.27  0.06  32
   16  Chicago  6/16/2015  2.62 -0.28  35
   17  Chicago  6/16/2015  1.96  0.09  37
   18  Chicago  6/16/2015  1.31  0.04  39
   19  Chicago  6/16/2015  0.65  0.02  34
   20  Chicago  6/16/2015  0.03  0.09  23
   21  Chicago  6/16/2015  0.58  0.03  36
   22  Chicago  6/16/2015  1.16  0.06  35
   23  Chicago  6/16/2015  2.31  0.05  36
   24  Chicago  6/16/2015  2.89 -0.41  20
   25  Chicago  6/16/2015  3.47 -0.38  35
   26      NYC  2/22/2015  6.55  0.10  36
   27      NYC  2/22/2015  3.93  0.16  21
   28      NYC  2/22/2015  3.27  0.06  32
   29      NYC  2/22/2015  2.62 -0.28  35
   30      NYC  2/22/2015  1.96  0.09  37
   31      NYC  2/22/2015  1.31  0.04  39
   32      NYC  2/22/2015  0.65  0.02  34
   33      NYC  2/22/2015  0.03  0.09  23
   34      NYC  2/22/2015  0.58  0.03  36
   35      NYC  2/22/2015  1.16  0.06  35
   36      NYC  2/22/2015  2.31  0.05  36
   37      NYC  2/22/2015  2.89 -0.41  20
   38      NYC  2/22/2015  3.47 -0.38  35
   39      NYC   5/5/2015  6.55  0.30  36
   40      NYC   5/5/2015  3.93  0.16  21
   41      NYC   5/5/2015  3.27  0.06  32
   42      NYC   5/5/2015  2.62 -0.28  35
   43      NYC   5/5/2015  1.96  0.09  37
   44      NYC   5/5/2015  1.31  0.04  39
   45      NYC   5/5/2015  0.65  0.02  34
   46      NYC   5/5/2015  0.03  0.09  23
   47      NYC   5/5/2015  0.58  0.03  36
   48      NYC   5/5/2015  1.16  0.06  35
   49      NYC   5/5/2015  2.31  0.05  36
   50      NYC   5/5/2015  2.89 -0.41  20
   51      NYC   5/5/2015  3.47 -0.38  35


def custom_func(group):
    # get index location of min-dist
    min_idx = group.dist.argmin()
    # processing upper side
    # ==================================================
    # reverse the order from first to min_idx
    temp1 = group.loc[min_idx:group.index[0]-1:-1].copy()
    # get the first negative trigger, use the cumsum trick
    temp1['is_capped'] = (temp1.a < 0).astype(int).cumsum().astype(bool)
    temp1['new_b'] = temp1.b[~temp1.is_capped]
    temp1 = temp1.fillna(method='ffill')
    # processing lower side
    # ==================================================
    # get index location of min-dist
    min_idx = group.dist.argmin()
    # reverse the order from first to min_idx
    temp2 = group.loc[min_idx:group.index[-1]+1:1].copy()
    # get the first negative trigger, use the cumsum trick
    temp2['is_capped'] = (temp2.a < 0).astype(int).cumsum().astype(bool)
    temp2['new_b'] = temp2.b[~temp2.is_capped]
    temp2 = temp2.fillna(method='ffill')
    # combine, min_idx row is duplicated
    # ==================================================
    res = temp1[::-1].append(temp2.iloc[1:])
    return res[['dist', 'a', 'b', 'is_capped', 'new_b']]

result = df.groupby(['City', 'date']).apply(custom_func).reset_index(level=['City', 'date'])

Out[394]: 
       City       date  dist     a   b is_capped  new_b
0   Chicago  5/25/2015  6.55  0.10  36      True     37
1   Chicago  5/25/2015  3.93  0.16  21      True     37
2   Chicago  5/25/2015  3.27  0.06  32      True     37
3   Chicago  5/25/2015  2.62 -0.28  35      True     37
4   Chicago  5/25/2015  1.96  0.09  37     False     37
5   Chicago  5/25/2015  1.31  0.04  39     False     39
6   Chicago  5/25/2015  0.65  0.02  34     False     34
7   Chicago  5/25/2015  0.03  0.09  23     False     23
8   Chicago  5/25/2015  0.58  0.03  36     False     36
9   Chicago  5/25/2015  1.16  0.06  35     False     35
10  Chicago  5/25/2015  2.31  0.05  36     False     36
11  Chicago  5/25/2015  2.89 -0.41  20      True     36
12  Chicago  5/25/2015  3.47 -0.38  35      True     36
13  Chicago  6/16/2015  6.55  0.30  36      True     37
14  Chicago  6/16/2015  3.93  0.16  21      True     37
15  Chicago  6/16/2015  3.27  0.06  32      True     37
16  Chicago  6/16/2015  2.62 -0.28  35      True     37
17  Chicago  6/16/2015  1.96  0.09  37     False     37
18  Chicago  6/16/2015  1.31  0.04  39     False     39
19  Chicago  6/16/2015  0.65  0.02  34     False     34
20  Chicago  6/16/2015  0.03  0.09  23     False     23
21  Chicago  6/16/2015  0.58  0.03  36     False     36
22  Chicago  6/16/2015  1.16  0.06  35     False     35
23  Chicago  6/16/2015  2.31  0.05  36     False     36
24  Chicago  6/16/2015  2.89 -0.41  20      True     36
25  Chicago  6/16/2015  3.47 -0.38  35      True     36
26      NYC  2/22/2015  6.55  0.10  36      True     37
27      NYC  2/22/2015  3.93  0.16  21      True     37
28      NYC  2/22/2015  3.27  0.06  32      True     37
29      NYC  2/22/2015  2.62 -0.28  35      True     37
30      NYC  2/22/2015  1.96  0.09  37     False     37
31      NYC  2/22/2015  1.31  0.04  39     False     39
32      NYC  2/22/2015  0.65  0.02  34     False     34
33      NYC  2/22/2015  0.03  0.09  23     False     23
34      NYC  2/22/2015  0.58  0.03  36     False     36
35      NYC  2/22/2015  1.16  0.06  35     False     35
36      NYC  2/22/2015  2.31  0.05  36     False     36
37      NYC  2/22/2015  2.89 -0.41  20      True     36
38      NYC  2/22/2015  3.47 -0.38  35      True     36
39      NYC   5/5/2015  6.55  0.30  36      True     37
40      NYC   5/5/2015  3.93  0.16  21      True     37
41      NYC   5/5/2015  3.27  0.06  32      True     37
42      NYC   5/5/2015  2.62 -0.28  35      True     37
43      NYC   5/5/2015  1.96  0.09  37     False     37
44      NYC   5/5/2015  1.31  0.04  39     False     39
45      NYC   5/5/2015  0.65  0.02  34     False     34
46      NYC   5/5/2015  0.03  0.09  23     False     23
47      NYC   5/5/2015  0.58  0.03  36     False     36
48      NYC   5/5/2015  1.16  0.06  35     False     35
49      NYC   5/5/2015  2.31  0.05  36     False     36
50      NYC   5/5/2015  2.89 -0.41  20      True     36
51      NYC   5/5/2015  3.47 -0.38  35      True     36
```

Comment: Thank you once again Jianxun.  Is there some straight forward way to get this information back to the original format with the new columns included?

Comment: @John You can simply `reset_index` in the last step. I've modified the code to fit your purpose.